# How are anti-unitary operators applied?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, hilbert-space

I was reading about [anti-unitary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator) from Wikipedia. They give an example of an anti-unitary operator:

[image]

were $K$ is complex conjugate operation. $\sigma_y$ is defined with respect to two orthonormal vectors spanning a 2-D Hilbert space $H$ say $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. Now if I have an initial vector as $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ would the operator $K$ apply only on complex number $\alpha,\beta$ ( result being $\alpha^*|0\rangle+\beta^*|1\rangle$  )  or on the vector $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$
aslo ? If it does what does it mean to take complex conjugate of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ ? My doubt arises because anti-unitaries not being linear can't be expressed only in terms of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antiunitary operator is an operator on the Hilbert space. Thus, it is nonsense to say that "the operator $K$ apply on complex number". Nevertheless, it can be shown that $U\alpha |\phi\rangle=\alpha^*U |\phi\rangle$, where $U$ is an antiunitary operator. $U|\phi\rangle$ should not be confused with $\langle\phi|$, the complex conjugate of $|\phi\rangle$.